# Dividing one SQL column into subgroups with headings

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, telerik, radcombobox

I have two tables

STATUS

```
SNO | STATUS | DEPARTMENT_ID

1   In progress      1
2    Assigned        2
3     Quoted         2
4   Development      3
```

DEPARTMENTS

```
SNO | DEPARTMENT |

1     DESIGNING
2     MARKETING
3     PRODUCTION
```

Now I want a result like this using SQL stored procedure

```
Some Custom Column Name | DEPARTMENT_ID

DESIGNING                      -
In Progress                    1
MARKETING                      -
Assigned                       2
Quoted                         2
PRODUCTION                     -
Development                    3
```

The custom column will be used to populate a Telerik RadComboBox with DESIGNING, MARKETING and PRODUCTION acting as separators between statuses.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Department, -1 from Department_Table
Union
Select StatusName, Department_ID from Status_Table
```

Please elaborate your question so that we can provide better answer. Currently it seems you just want to return the joined data of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Often, this type of operation is more easily done at the application level.  You *can* do it in SQL, using `union all` and `order by`,  however:

```
select status as CustomColumnName, department
from ((select s.status, d.department, 1 as ordering
       from status s join
            departments d
            on s.department_id = d.sno
      ) union all
      (select d.department, NULL, 0 as ordering
       from departments d
      )
     ) dd
order by CustomColumnName, ordering;
```

Note:  this treats the `-` as `NULL`.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. I missed the ordering part.

Comment: the ordering part is needed?

Comment: @KalaiarasanManimaran . . . Yes.  The OP seems to have a specific ordering in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Is it ok with other sample data ?

```
DECLARE @STATUS TABLE (
    SNO INT
    ,[STATUS] VARCHAR(50)
    ,DEPARTMENT_ID INT
    )

INSERT INTO @STATUS
VALUES (1,'In progress' ,1)
    ,(2,'Assigned',2)
    ,(3,'Quoted',2)
    ,(4,'Development',3)

DECLARE @DEPARTMENT TABLE (SNO INT,DEPARTMENT VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @DEPARTMENT
VALUES (    1,'DESIGNING'),(2,'MARKETING')
    ,(3,'PRODUCTION')
    --select * from @STATUS
    --select * from @DEPARTMENT
    ;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT DEPARTMENT [CustomeColumn]
        ,'-' DEPARTMENT_ID
        ,sno
    FROM @DEPARTMENT

    UNION ALL

    SELECT [STATUS]
        ,cast(DEPARTMENT_ID AS VARCHAR(10))
        ,(
            SELECT sno
            FROM @DEPARTMENT
            WHERE sno = a.DEPARTMENT_ID
            )
    FROM @STATUS A
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY sno
```